# Ordenar sequência de números em banco de dados com PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou com dificuldade em desenvolver um sistema que faz a alteração de uma sequência de números. Preciso dessa sequência para dispor itens na ordem correta. Ao salvar um item no banco, o mesmo recebe um número para a sequencia 1, 2, 3... e assim sucessivamente.

Resolvi modificar e tentar explicar melhor, a lista abaixo, vem de um banco de dados, o primeiro numero só mostra o id do banco o segundo a ordem em que foram salvas, o restante é só descrição. Quero saber como modificar essa ordem ao clicar em um dos itens. Na foto o item 2 está selecionado, nesse caso, quando eu clicar na seta para cima quero que o 2 passe a ser 1 e o 1 passe a ser 2. Como posso fazer esse algoritmo?

```
$mo = $maxOrder - 1; //ultima numeração de ordem da materia menos 1

        if($ordem == 1){ //se ordem atual for o primeiro registro

            $result = $ordem + $mo; //soma-se ortem atual com $mo para ficar por ultimo

        }elseif($ordem == $maxOrder){ //ou se ordem for a ultima

            $result = $ordem - 1; //subtrai-se por 1 para passar a ser a primeira

        }else{
            $result = $ordem + 1; //senão soma-se com 1 para subir
        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para resgatar esses dados eu mando uma requisição através do angular para a function abaixo, nela, chamo o model que faz o select, armazeno o resultado em um objeto e depois percorro o objeto com um foreach e armazeno o resultado em array de nome data. depois disso retorno os dados via json com json_encode(). Segue o códico citado:

```
public function getMateriaByPortaria()
{

  $this->layout=""; //retornar dados numa tela sem layout

  $materias = $this->PortariaMateriaM->get_all_portaria_materia(); //pega todos os dados da tabela portaria_has_materia

  $data = array(); //array data

  foreach ($materias as $mat) { //foreach que percorre o objeto e armazena no array data
        $data[] = array(
            "idportaria_materia" => $mat->idportaria_materia,
            "ordem" => $mat->ordem,
            "numerada" => $mat->numerada,
            "idportaria" => $mat->idportaria,
            "data_inicio" => $mat->data_inicio,
            "data_fim" => $mat->data_fim,
            "titulo" => $mat->titulo,
            "descricao" => $mat->descricao,
            "descricao_internacional" => $mat->descricao_internacional,
            "assinatura_instrutor" => $mat->assinatura_instrutor,
            "sigla" => $mat->sigla,
            "idmateria" => $mat->idmateria,
            "nome_materia" => $mat->nome_materia,
            "nome_ingles" => $mat->nome_ingles,
            "numero_tempo" => $mat->numero_tempo,
            "carga_horaria" => $mat->carga_horaria,
            "modulo" => $mat->modulo
        );
    }

    print_r(json_encode($data));
    return json_encode($data); //retorna dados do array em json

}
```

Comment: O problema que você está tendo é que quando a `ordem` de algo muda, ela repete com outra igual? E você quer evitar isso para que fique diferentes?

Comment: isso aí, elas ficam iguais, quero que fiquem distintas, em sequencia, 1, 2, 3...

Comment: Tanto faz se a ordem começar com 0 ao invés de 1? Tipo 0,1,2,3...

Comment: Se não retornar repetido, sim.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que o que você queira seja mudar a ordenação e assim alterar as outras sequências evitando que exista 2 valores iguais. Você pode estar fazendo o seguinte!

Vamos supor que tem as seguintes variáveis:

```
// array com os valores obtidos
$frutas = array(
    0 => 'maça',
    1 => 'banana',
    2 => 'morango',
    3 => 'melância',
    4 => 'laranja'
);

$maxOrder = count($itens); // 4
```

Utilizando esta função você consegue alterar a posição sem que repita

```
function sequencia($array, $keyArray, $position)
{
    $i = 0; // valor inicial

    // verifica se a posição que pede é primeira ou última
    switch ($position) {
        case 'first':
            $position = $i;
            break;
        case 'last':
            $position = count($array);
    }

    // reorganiza o array
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($keyArray < $position) {
            if ($key != $keyArray && $key != $position) {
                $result[$i] = $value;
            } elseif ($key == $position) {
                $result[$i] = $array[$key];
            }
        } else {
            if ($key != $keyArray && $key != $position) {
                $result[$i] = $value;
            } elseif ($key == $position) {
                $i++;
                $result[$i] = $value;
            } elseif ($key == $keyArray) {
                $result[$position] = $array[$keyArray];
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

**Exemplos**

Quero que a `banana` vá para a posição **3** você utiliza

```
sequencia($frutas, 1, 3);
```

Quero que a `laranja` vá para a posição **1**

```
sequencia($frutas, 4, 1);
```

Você também pode estar utilizando os argumentos `first` ou `last` para primeiro e últimas posições

```
sequencia($frutas, 3, 'first'); // muda posição para primeiro da lista
sequencia($frutas, 2, 'last'); // muda posição para último da lista
```

> Edição para adaptar com a nova adição da pergunta

Entendi o que você quis dizer, no caso é só você adicionar os valores da variável `$result` para o banco de dados.

**Exemplo com MySQL:**

*Antes:*

```
$result[$i] = $array[$key];
```

*Depois:*

```
$conn->prepare("UPDATE tabela SET ordem = $array[$key] WHERE ordem = $i");
```

Espero que tenha ajudado!

Comment: Até dá uma luz cara mas ainda não é isso.
Tenho por que os valores tem que vir em ordem do banco, eu posso mudar a posição do array mas quando forem listados vão aparecer na ordem em que foram salvos da primeira vez.

Comment: Poderia me explicar melhor como você os pega do banco de dados? Com isso da pra me basear

Comment: estou pegando os dados com ngrepeat do angularjs, Mas trazer os dados não é o problema isso ta fazendo de boa. Modifiquei a pergunta, vê se assim da uma esclarecida. E obrigado pelas respostas!

Comment: Não no caso o que eu gostaria de saber como você obtêm os dados dentro do PHP, eles ficam armazenados em um `array`, `objeto`, etc... A edição da sua pergunta ajudou a esclarecer, mas eu não tenho como te dar uma resposta realmente certa se não souber como você armazena os dados para uso

Comment: Vinicius, me desculpe a demora pra responder, estou sem internet em casa, estou armazenando os dados dentro de um objeto, depois percorro o mesmo com um foreach e aí sim armazeno o mesmo dentro de um array. amanhã no trabalho vou postar o código do php para esclarecer mais.

Comment: Editei, agradeço muito sua ajuda!

Comment: Diga se a edição tenha ficado confusa!

Comment: Kra muito obrigado, acho que vai funcionar, no momento estou fazendo manutenção em outro projeto, e não to podendo testar, mas acho que dessa vez vai. Posso te perturbar mais se não der certo? rs

Comment: Sim a vontade :D

Comment: @FlavioHenrique resolveu seu problema?

Comment: Então Vinicius, me desculpe a demora, não consegui resolver ainda, mas to tirando o resto do dia pra tentar resolver. Te mando um feedback até o fim do dia.

Comment: Vinicius ainda não consegui, ta difícil de organizar um array e passar os valores, amanhã vou tentar novamente. Obrigado pela ajuda, mais uma vez!

Comment: Kra não consegui fazer.... não to entendendo